# HTML EMAILERS / Anchor links

Tags: html-email, mailchimp

Quick question, is it ok to use standard HTML anchor links within a html emailer?  Its to be used as a jump link to content within the e-mail.  Wondered if anyone had any experience of this and whether they had come across any issues / pitfalls?  It's come from a client request.  Only thing I can think of is that the link colour may be over-ridden in some email clients.

Comment: Anchor links work to some degree in email clients. Outlook in particular is notorious and had jumps to a different places. iOS and others were fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Anchor links only working in browser but not in in HTML email (Outlook)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190390/anchor-links-only-working-in-browser-but-not-in-in-html-email-outlook)

Comment: Yep thats all i need to know - thanks @Syfer - happy to give you a tick if add as answer

Answer (score 0):

Anchor links work to some degree in email clients. Outlook in particular is notorious and had jumps to a different places. iOS and others were fine.